# JSON must be no more than 1000000 bytes

Tags: node.js, nginx, jenkins, chef-infra

We have a Jenkins-Chef setup with a QA build project to a website for a client. The build gets the code from Bitbucket, and a script uploads the cookbooks from the Chef Client to the Chef Server.

These builds ran fine for a long time. Two days ago the automated and manual builds started failing with the following error (taken from the Jenkins console output):

> Updated Environment qa
>
> Uploading example-deployment [0.1.314]
>
> ERROR: Request Entity Too Large
>
> Response: JSON must be no more than 1000000 bytes.

From what I understand, JSON files are supposed to be related to nodejs which is what the developers use on this webserver.

We looked all over the config files for Jenkins, the Chef-Server and the QA server. We couldn't find a way to change this 1MB limit that is causing this error.

We tried changing client_max_body_size, didn't work.
We checked the JSON files size, non of them reach this limit.
Any idea where we can find a solution? Can this limit be changed? Is there anything we can do (Infrastructure wise) or should this be fixed from the developer side?

Comment: The message is due to your cookbook being too large, the request to upload it exceed the 1MB limit, usually it means you have other problem of speed on your deployment as a cookbook this big is problematic.

Comment: The size of the cookbook seems to be around 60MB, unless I'm looking in the wrong place? (im in /home/ubuntu/chef-repo/cookbooks). How can a dev pushing a change increase the size that much?

Comment: Maybe he put a apckage in the files of the cookbook `example-deployment` a `du -hs /home/ubuntu/chef-repo/cookbooks/example-deployment` should give you the size of each part of this cookbook

Comment: seems /chef-repo/cookbooks/example-deployment/files/default/website/.git/ contains 56MB out of 62MB.. not sure what to do? Should I ask the devs to look into this? should I delete these and give building it a try?

Comment: Add a file named <dot>chefignore just under cookbooks and add <dot>git inside to avoid uploading it to the chef-server see https://docs.chef.io/chef_repo.html#chefignore-files but git should already be ignored, so look the rest of the cookbook for large images/binary files

Comment: ٍSorry for the very late reply. I created .chefignore and added .git (55 MB) and another directory (containing another 5 MB). Still getting the same error unfortunately.

Comment: My bad, the file name is only `chefignore` without the dot. Content of the file should be wildcard paths, so here `*/.git/*` should do.

Comment: Did the wildcard paths, but not without the dot (I thought the dot was just to hide files on linux?). I'll see if can get access to run more tests.

Comment: Indeed they are by convention not listed, but the `.`  is part of the file name and I wrote from phone not re-reading properly the link I gave on previous comment, sorry

Comment: This worked. Cookbooks upload normally now and builds are back running. Thanks for the help, now to find a way to mark this as an answer.

Comment: Wrote a summary as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all, the 1M value is more or less hardcoded, the chef-server is not intended to store large objects.

What happens is before uploading a cookbook, a json file with it's information is created, as this file will be stored in DB and indexed it should not exceed a too large size to avoid performances problems.

The idea is to upload to the chef-server only what is absolutely necessary, strip CVS directory, any IDE build/project file, etc.

Best solution to achieve it simply is using the [chefignore file](https://docs.chef.io/chef_repo.html#chefignore-files). It has to be created just under the cookbook_path.

The content of this is wildcard matches to ignore while uploading the cookbook so an example one could be:

```
*/.svn/* # To strip subversion directories
*/.git/* # To strip git directories
*~ # to ignore vim backup files
```