# chef-client error "JSON must be no more than 1000000 bytes"

Tags: chef-infra

I have a slightly different problem than I have been able to find discussed previously.  It is a problems similar to [JSON must be no more than 1000000 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500515/json-must-be-no-more-than-1000000-bytes), but instead of happening on cookbook upload, it is happening at the end of my chef-client run.  Running chef-client --log_level debug, I am able to see the JSON that the chef-client run has collected about my workstation.  And, yes, it runs on to 1016064 bytes.

Now some of the bloat that caused me to cross the 1000000 byte limit when I had run chef-client successfully before, came from an extra set of temporary NFS mounts that I had at the time, but there is just a lot of bloat from our massive corporate /etc/group file among other things.  Thus we have been obviously dancing near this limit for some time now.

So, assuming that as in the question referenced above there is no way to increase this arbitrary limit, is there a way to limit the information that the chef-client run is trying to report back to the server?

Comment: You can try running `chef-client --minimal-ohai`. That would run only some ohai plugins, thus will not add many automatic attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion of --minimal-ohai is definitely an option.  Unfortunately, I am actually using some of the ohai stuff, so that is a bit too big of a hammer for my purposes.

I have found my answer here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-infra/infrastructure/issues/1027.  There is a way to increase the allowed data payload size.  The fix is to add the following lines to the /etc/opscode/chef-server.rb file:

```
opscode_erchef['max_request_size'] = "4000000"
opscode_solr4['max_field_length'] = "300000"
```

Your size needs may vary.